# Makefile: how to loop on data to set arguments within the script?

Tags: console, makefile

**Given a working makefile** which crop a world map to a specific country's bounding box.

```
# boxing: 
INDIA_crop.tif: ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif
    gdal_translate -projwin 67.0 37.5 99.0 05.0 ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif INDIA_crop.tif
    # ulx uly lrx lry  // W N E S
# unzip:
ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif: ETOPO1.zip
    unzip ETOPO1.zip
    touch ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif
# download:
ETOPO1.zip:
    curl -o ETOPO1.zip 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'
clean:
    rm `ls | grep -v 'zip' | grep -v 'Makefile'`
```

**Given I currently have to change this makefile each time by hand editing** the makefile to change:

```
1. the country name, 
2. its North border geocoordinate, 
3. its South border geocoordinate, 
4. its East border geocoordinate, 
5. its West border geocoordinate.
```

**Given I also have a dataset for all countries** such :

```
   data = [  
    { "W":-62.70; "S":-27.55;"E": -54.31; "N":-19.35; "item":"Paraguay"  },
    { "W": 50.71; "S": 24.55;"E":  51.58; "N": 26.11; "item":"Qatar"     },
    { "W": 20.22; "S": 43.69;"E":  29.61; "N": 48.22; "item":"Romania"   }, 
    { "W": 19.64; "S": 41.15;"E":-169.92; "N": 81.25; "item":"Russia"    }, 
    { "W": 29.00; "S": -2.93;"E":  30.80; "N": -1.14; "item":"Rwanda"    },
    { "W": 34.62; "S": 16.33;"E":  55.64; "N": 32.15; "item":"Saudi Arabia"}
    ];
```

**How to loop on each line of the data so to set parameters into my makefile ?** So I output at once all the files `COUNTRYNAME_crop.tif` with the correct bounding boxes.

Comment: Ugh, your `clean` target is rather painful, I'm afraid. How about `$(RM) $(filter-out $(wildcard *.zip) Makefile,$(wildcard *))` ... Admittedly not a lot more elegant, but at least avoids the sticky issue of [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using GNU make, this seems to me like a perfect problem for autogenerated makefiles.  After make reads in its makefiles it will test each one as if it were a target to see if it can be rebuilt.  If so, and it is rebuilt, make will automatically re-exec itself.  This is an extraordinarily powerful type of meta-programming.  I would combine this with recursive variable naming.

**1. Data:** Let's assume your dataset is in `dataset.out` such :

```
[  
    { "W":-62.70; "S":-27.55;"E": -54.31; "N":-19.35; "item":"Paraguay"  },
    { "W": 50.71; "S": 24.55;"E":  51.58; "N": 26.11; "item":"Qatar"     },
    { "W": 20.22; "S": 43.69;"E":  29.61; "N": 48.22; "item":"Romania"   }, 
    { "W": 19.64; "S": 41.15;"E":-169.92; "N": 81.25; "item":"Russia"    }, 
    { "W": 29.00; "S": -2.93;"E":  30.80; "N": -1.14; "item":"Rwanda"    },
    { "W": 34.62; "S": 16.33;"E":  55.64; "N": 32.15; "item":"Saudi Arabia"}
];
```

**2. Converter:** Now you need to write the utility `convert-to-makefile`.  I would write it in Perl myself but the new kids would probably choose Python.  Whatever.  Anyway, for each country, the output should be something like this:

```
COUNTRIES += <countryname>
<countryname>-NORTH := <north-coord>
<countryname>-SOUTH := <south-coord>
<countryname>-EAST  := <east-coord>
<countryname>-WEST  := <west-coord>
```

so that `bounding.mk`, after being generated, has one of those stanzas for each country.

**3a. Makefile:** Then, add this to the beginning of your makefile:

```
-include bounding.mk
```

**3b.** Then add this rule to the end of your makefile:

```
bounding.mk: dataset.out
         convert-to-makefile $< > $@
```

**3c.** Then you can write your rules like this:

```
all: $(COUNTRIES:%=%_crop.tif)

%_crop.tif: ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif
        gdal_translate -projwin $($*-WEST) $($*-NORTH) $($*-EAST) $($*-SOUTH) $< $@
```

That should about do it!

Comment: thanks for this dump of tips, I will attack this tomorrow to get somtething working.

Comment: `$<` is input file (ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif), `$@` is output file (*_crop.tif).

Comment: I made a revamp of your answer as I restart my assault on this issue.

Comment: Question: `bounding.mk: dataset.out ; convert-to-makefile $< > $@` should be `bounding.mk: dataset.out ; convert-to-makefile dataset.out > dataset_makefile.out`, right ?

Comment: No... why would it be that?  There's no mention of `dataset_makefile.out` anywhere that I can see.  Each make rule should create/update the target exactly (that's the value if `$@`), not some other target.

Comment: In *3b*, don't understand what is `$< > $@`. Could you add a short comment, as well as for *3c* 's `$(COUNTRIES:%=%_crop.tif)`

Comment: All is explained in the GNU make manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html  In particular, for `$<` and `$@` look at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html and for `$(COUNTRIES:%=%_crop.tif)` look at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html

Comment: Thanks, I will find a way out of this. Thanks for the good help.